# Poco HTTPServer

Tags: c++, sockets, poco

I am using Poco::Net::HTTPServer. I can set the port, but how can I set the listening interface/address? It defaults to 0.0.0.0

```
Poco::UInt16 port = 4000;
Poco::Net::ServerSocket socket(port);
Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams *pParams = new 
Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams();
pParams->setMaxQueued(100);
pParams->setMaxThreads(16);
Poco::Net::HTTPServer server(new HandleFactory(this->licenseServer),     socket, pParams);
server.start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ServerSocket` has a few versions of its constructor, instead of

```
ServerSocket(Uint16 port, int)
```

you should use

```
ServerSocket(
  const SocketAddress & address,
  int backlog = 64
);
```

and construct `SocketAddress` passing first argument as IP address (it can be string object) and second argument as port:

```
Poco::UInt16 port = 4000;
Poco::Net::ServerSocket socket(Poco::Net::SocketAddress("0.0.0.0",port));
```